# Como alinhar sempre para o top uma LI

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para que essas imagens sempre fiquem encostada no `footer` da outra.

As debaixo devem sempre encostar no `footer` das de cima no formato de uma `li`.

Segue abaixo a print:

<kbd>[image: Exemplo]</kbd>

Meu código está assim:

```html
<style> 
  li { margin-top: 20px; list-style: none; float: left; align-items: top; } 
</style>
<div id="header"> 
   <ul class="tabs">
       <div id="thePic"></div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Estranho, nesse seu `CSS` que postou não tem `<li>` rsrs. Mas tenta tirar aquele `margin-top` da `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que quando diz `footer` quer dizer `bottom`. Primeiro, é errado isto:

```
   <ul class="tabs">
       <div id="thePic"></div>
   </ul>
```

única tag que pode ter entre `<ul></ul>` é `<li></li>`
Para deixar alinhado a partir do bottom pode usar `display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;`:

```
<style> 
  li { margin-top: 20px; list-style: none; display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;} 
</style>
<div id="header"> 
   <ul class="tabs">
       <li><img src=""/></li>
       <li><img src=""/></li>
       <li><img src=""/></li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

exemplo:

```css
.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.after-box {
    border: 3px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box" style="height:40px">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
```

saiba mais sobre [display:inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) e [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)